# React Native Expo build:web blank page

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I've got an existing React Native project which builds for iOS, Android and I can run in the web with the expo start command, but I am unable to run expo build:web and run it locally with

```
npx serve web-build
```

The console in the blank page shows :

`ReferenceError: Platform is not defined`

In my code I have the following:

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView
behavior={Platform.OS == "ios" ? "padding" : "height"}
style={styles.container}
>
```

If I try to deploy the same code to Amplify via Git connections, it returns an error such as

`No such file ./components/myComponent.js`

I am not sure why it won't run on either web deployments

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to import Platform:

```
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
```